# renderPlot with specific height doesn't allow to show a table next (Shiny)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, histogram, facet-grid

I am trying to plot an histogram and next, a table. However, since I want a specific height, the table (which must appear after the histogram) starts in the middle of the histogram. Moreover, I would like to show a title before the table. (How could I a write a proper title before the table? Because I wrote "renderText" but it doesn't look very good).

What should I do?

If I delete "height" the table appears well.

Here you have an example of my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

################### DATA ########################
val <- c(2.1490626,3.7928443,2.2035281,1.5927854,3.1399245,2.3967338,3.7915825,4.6691277,3.0727319,2.9230937,2.6239759,3.7664386,4.0160378,1.2500835,4.7648343,0.0000000,5.6740227,2.7510256,3.0709322,2.7998003,4.0809085,2.5178086,5.9713330,2.7779843,3.6724801,4.2648527,3.6841084,2.5597235,3.8477471,2.6587736,2.2742209,4.5862788,6.1989269,4.1167091,3.1769325,4.2404515,5.3627032,4.1576810,4.3387921,1.4024381,0.0000000,4.3999099,3.4381837,4.8269218,2.6308474,5.3481382,4.9549753,4.5389650,1.3002293,2.8648220,2.4015338,2.0962332,2.6774765,3.0581759,2.5786137,5.0539080,3.8545796,4.3429043,4.2233248,2.0434363,4.5980727)
df1 <- data.frame(val)
df1$type <- "Type 1"

val <- c(3.7691229,3.6478055,0.5435826,1.9665861,3.0802654,1.2248374,1.7311236,2.2492826,2.2365337,1.5726119,2.0147144,2.3550348,1.9527204,3.3689502,1.7847986,3.5901329,1.6833872,3.4240479,1.8372175,0.0000000,2.5701453,3.6551315,4.0327091,3.8781182)
df2 <- data.frame(val)
df2$type <- "Type 2"

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)


################ SHINY APP ########################
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Histogram"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("hist"),
      textOutput("text"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot(height=700,{
    p <- ggplot(df3, aes(val, fill=type)) +
      geom_histogram(position = "identity", colour = "grey40", bins = 10) +
      ggtitle("Here must be a title") +
      xlab("Values") +
      ylab("Frequency") +
      facet_grid(type ~ .) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(as.matrix(df3$val), n=10))
    
    p + theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(),
              strip.text.y = element_blank())
    
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText("People with these values: ")
  output$table <- renderTable(df3)
  
} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here you can see the problem:
[image: problem]

Thanks very much in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

The idea is that I should have moved "height" in the ui instead of being in the server.           `plotOutput("hist", height=700)`

To put some space between the plot and the table, it can be solved writing `br()`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

################### DATA ########################
val <- c(2.1490626,3.7928443,2.2035281,1.5927854,3.1399245,2.3967338,3.7915825,4.6691277,3.0727319,2.9230937,2.6239759,3.7664386,4.0160378,1.2500835,4.7648343,0.0000000,5.6740227,2.7510256,3.0709322,2.7998003,4.0809085,2.5178086,5.9713330,2.7779843,3.6724801,4.2648527,3.6841084,2.5597235,3.8477471,2.6587736,2.2742209,4.5862788,6.1989269,4.1167091,3.1769325,4.2404515,5.3627032,4.1576810,4.3387921,1.4024381,0.0000000,4.3999099,3.4381837,4.8269218,2.6308474,5.3481382,4.9549753,4.5389650,1.3002293,2.8648220,2.4015338,2.0962332,2.6774765,3.0581759,2.5786137,5.0539080,3.8545796,4.3429043,4.2233248,2.0434363,4.5980727)
df1 <- data.frame(val)
df1$type <- "Type 1"

val <- c(3.7691229,3.6478055,0.5435826,1.9665861,3.0802654,1.2248374,1.7311236,2.2492826,2.2365337,1.5726119,2.0147144,2.3550348,1.9527204,3.3689502,1.7847986,3.5901329,1.6833872,3.4240479,1.8372175,0.0000000,2.5701453,3.6551315,4.0327091,3.8781182)
df2 <- data.frame(val)
df2$type <- "Type 2"

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)


################ SHINY APP ########################
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Histogram"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("hist", height=700),
      br(),
      br(),
      textOutput("text"),
      br(),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(df3, aes(val, fill=type)) +
      geom_histogram(position = "identity", colour = "grey40", bins = 10) +
      ggtitle("Here must be a title") +
      xlab("Values") +
      ylab("Frequency") +
      facet_grid(type ~ .) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(as.matrix(df3$val), n=10))
    
    p + theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(),
              strip.text.y = element_blank())
    
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText("People with these values: ")
  output$table <- renderTable(df3)
  
} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```